# SK subview color doesn't change to it's .backgroundColor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skview

I am trying to make an overlaying view which just makes the screen turn red. However, even if I set the background color to any color, it just shows as gray. I can still maneuver it around the screen, I just can't change the color for some reason.

Here's what I put into my didMove to view function:

```
let pulseView = SKView(frame: self.view!.frame)
pulseView.backgroundColor = SKColor.red
pulseView.alpha = 1
self.view?.addSubview(pulseView)
```

Comment: Dont use SKView, just use a regular UIView.  SKView is going to render an SKScene.  Of course. I wouldnt even do this either.  If you want the scene to turn red, add an SKCameraNode, and then attach a red node to the camera

Comment: Thanks! Using a UIView did the trick.